# Как обновить datatable уже с новым ajax.data

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, datatable

Нужно чтобы при нажатие на кнопки, которые уже добавлены менялось значение переменной tabck(ее я отправляю в ajax) и обновлялся datatable. Переменная меняется но вот таблицу уже с новым запросом отправить не могу. Спасибо!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let tabck = 3;

        let table;

        table =  $('#tableAds').dataTable({
            dom: "<'row py-2'<'col text-center text-md-right'B>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'table-responsive'tr>>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'p>>",
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            searching: true,
            ordering: false,
            responsive: true,
            info: false,
            ajax: {
                url: 'get',
                data: {'select_tab':tabck}
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'client.id.username'},
                {data: 'description'},
                {data:   null,render: getCeck  },
                {data: null}
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 4,
                width: "autoWidth",
                data: "download_link",
                render: function (data) {
                    return '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Action"> ' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="location.href=\'/admin/ads/' + data.id + '/show\'"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></button>' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="location.href=\'/admin/ads/' + data.id + '/edit\'"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="location.href=\'/admin/ads/' + data.id + '/delete\'"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></button>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
            }],
            language: {
                url: "/data/Russian.json"
            },
            buttons: {

                buttons: [{
                    className: 'btn  btn-secondary trigger-hidden',
                    text: '_',
                    action: function () {
                        tabck = 3;
                        table.draw();
                    },
                },
                    {
                        className: 'btn   btn-info trigger-hidden',
                        text: '_',
                        action: function () {
                            tabck = 1;
                            table.draw();
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        className: 'btn  btn-danger trigger-hidden',
                        text: ' _  ',
                        action: function () {
                            tabck = 2;
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        className: 'btn   btn-warning trigger-hidden',
                        text: '  _ ',
                        action: function () {
                            tabck = 0;
                            alert('0');
                        },
                    },
                ]
            },


        });

    });
```

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778389/how-to-manually-update-datatables-table-with-new-json-data

Comment: Это не то. Мне нужно просто обновить таблицу.

Comment: Вам нужно заново получить JSON данные в таблицу?

Comment: Да нужно заново получить )

Comment: сделайте функцию `refreshTable(mass)` которая по массиву данных будет рисовать таблицу (или в сущ таблице заменять). И потом работайте с массивом (при изменении которого вы будите делать `refreshTable(mass)`. А `mass` - то ваш полученный `json` с сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table =  $('#tableAds').dataTable
```

`datatable` нужно было написать с заглавной буквой т.е Datatable.

Если так взять то оба варианта рабочие но если вы собираетесь использовать этот объект повторно, то нужно писать с заглавной.